# Generator of intersection of ideals in a PID via adjunction?

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

In a PID we have the formulas $ \left\langle f\right\rangle + \left\langle g \right\rangle = \left\langle \gcd(f,g) \right\rangle $ and $ \left\langle f\right\rangle \cap \left\langle g \right\rangle = \left\langle \operatorname{lcm}(f,g) \right\rangle $. Now intersection is the product in the lattice of ideals ordered by inclusion, while the $\gcd$ is the product in the lattice of elements of the PID ordered by divisibility. If $ \left\langle \cdot \right\rangle$ had left and right adjoints, this formula would pop out for free. Can $ \left\langle \cdot \right\rangle$ be seen as a functor? Does it have adjoints?

Answer (score 3):

The question is not precise, but one way to think about this is that the ideals of $R$ form a sub-poset of the powerset of $R$: write $I(R) \subseteq P(R)$. Then $\langle \cdot \rangle: P(R) \to I(R)$ is left adjoint to the inclusion. This doesn't take advantage of the PID structure, though.

The most straightforward way to view a ring $R$ itself as a category is to take its multiplicative monoid. The most straightforward way to view the ideals $I(R)$ of a ring as a category is to view it as a poset. If we view it this way, $\langle \cdot \rangle$ is not in any way a functor -- it takes morphisms of $R$ to objects of $I(R)$, which is not even the right data.